# load video from File Path

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am trying to Load video from Path in my file system Project , i have code for the URL stream

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"US_Very_High_Dive_Boudia_US_44_x264" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];


MPMoviePlayerController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
```

Comment: Is your `player` object allocated? If so, your edit is unrelated to your original question. Please revert the edit and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. `MPMoviePlayer` knows best when to load data. Convert the file path to a `NSURL`, or even better, just use

```
NSURL *myURL =`[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"US_Very_High_Dive_Boudia_US_44_x264" withExtension:@"mp4"];`
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
```

Comment: Error :no visible @interface for 'nsbundle' declares the selector 'URLForResource:ofType:'

Comment: I was writing off the top of my head, fixed it. You should really learn how to read the documentation though...

Comment: okay i am trying now , i just updated my question , but its not loading now

Comment: you can Also flag hear of close answer its also duplicate mate